# visualizador de windows no puede abrir esta imagen porque no tiene permisos de acceso correctos php

Tags: php

**Crea la carpeta y mueve el archivo el problema es al visualizar la imagen**

```
if (isset($_FILES['comDom'])) {
mkdir("../../pruebasImagen/$carpeta", 0777);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['comDom']['tmp_name'],"../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta. "/".$nombre);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Identi']['tmp_name'], "../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta. "/". $nombre2);
```

}

Comment: adjunta por favor exactamente cual es el problema

Comment: El problema es que no puedo abrir la imagen amigo, si la sube al servidor y todo, pero el problema es exactamente ese, que no las puedo abrir porque no tiene permisos

Comment: **intenté lo siguiente pero igual sigue sin abrir** `if (isset($_FILES['comDom'])) {
    mkdir("../../pruebasImagen/$carpeta", 0777);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['comDom']['tmp_name'],"../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta. "/".$nombre);
    chmod("../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta. "/".$nombre, 0755);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Identi']['tmp_name'], "../../pruebasImagen/".$carpeta. "/". $nombre2);
}
 `

Comment: Es posible que la ruta "../../" esta detrás del home, en tal caso siempre retornara 403 el servidor, podría detallar que error te retorna.

Comment: La imagen si la mueve a la ubicación deseada, el problema es que no la abre, el visor de imágenes me dice que no tengo permisos

Comment: En el error.log de apache, deberías tener un mensaje de error diciendo algo así como que las rutas de las imágenes están fuera del open_basedir, en cuyo caso solo tienes que o bien cambiar la ruta de las imágenes o añadir la ruta al open_basedir.

Comment: el problema está en que no se asignan los permisos para ver imagen y solo en windows porque en el navegador si se puede visualizar